# Parent Controller blocking child table view UITableViewRowAction swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using library call Page-Menu (https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu) which allow me to add child view controllers in view controller. i can scroll between this view controllers.In one of the child view controller I'm using UITableView.i am using UITableViewRowAction to delete cell but. Don't know why but table not detecting swipe gesture. if i disable Page-menu scrolling then table-view UITableViewRowAction working. i searched lots about this in google. i didn't find any solution. Thanks

[image: attached the screenshot of my app]

Comment: share your code please

Comment: which part code you want to see. because there's lots of code :D

Comment: glad to see code that "related for this question", could be even better suspicious part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having played a bit with the library, I found the issue is to do with disabling scroll view gesture recogniser in the `CAPSPageMenu` view controller.

Follow these steps to enable table view editing in one of the child view controllers.

Subclass a `UIScrollView` like this for the `PageMenu` target:

```
class CustomScrollView : UIScrollView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

  override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    return true
  }

  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return ((self.delegate as! CAPSPageMenu).gestureDelegate?.gestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith(gestureRecognizer, otherGestureRecognizer: otherGestureRecognizer))!
  }
}
```

Then in `CAPSPageMenu`, replace:

`let controllerScrollView = UIScrollView()`

with

`let controllerScrollView = CustomScrollView()`

Declare a protocol in the same file:

```
@objc public protocol CustomGestureDelegate {
  func gestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
}
```

And add this property to `CAPSPageMenu`:

```
open weak var gestureDelegate: CustomGestureDelegate?
```

Here I have made `controllerArray` as a property in `ViewController` so we can filter out the view controllers with a table view later.

```
var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []
```

Then make `ViewController` conform to `CustomGestureDelegate` with `ViewController: UIViewController, CustomGestureDelegate`, and set this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
pageMenu!.gestureDelegate = self
```

Implement this function in `ViewController` (your container view controller):

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
  if pageMenu?.currentPageIndex == 0 {
  return (controllerArray[0] as! CustomGestureDelegate).gestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith(gestureRecognizer, otherGestureRecognizer: otherGestureRecognizer)
  }
  return true
}
```

You can add similar logic for other child view controllers with table views. Here I assumed only the initial view controller had a table view.

Make your child view controllers conform to `CustomGestureDelegate` by adding the following implementation:

```
class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController, CustomGestureDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
    let path = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
    if path != nil {
      gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
    }
    gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
    return true
  }
}
```

I hope this helped you.

UPDATE:

Check out https://github.com/LemonSpike/PageMenu to see a demo of this for `PageMenuDemoStoryboard` target.

Comment: can you explain your code? . self.tableView showing error

Comment: it will be great if you give example. because I'm new at swift

Comment: @JayPatel I have added some extra explanation. let me know if this works.

Comment: i tried but still not working. This " func gestureRecognizerShouldReceiveTouch(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,_ touch: UITouch) -> Bool" not getting called.

Comment: have you set breakpoints for the original `UIGestureRecogniserDelegate` method, to check if that is getting called?

Comment: Yes @Pranav Kasetti. i also checked by adding breakpoints.but not getting called. is it working for you?

Comment: @JayPatel With the above edited code, my code is working. If this helped you, please accept answer.

Comment: Thank you For answer. can you create demo and upload in github and share a link?. if so then that will be so much helpful.

Comment: @JayPatel Have just updated answer with a link to the GitHub demo. Please up vote and accept if this helped. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks lot Pranav Kasetti for help. you saved lots of time.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: Hi, Can you help me with this question again?

Comment: As you disable scrolling over the UITableViewCell. i have to allow that to. I archive that by just removing that by just returning true in gestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith Method. But it conflicting with cell touches. if i scroll child view from UITableViewCell it actually scroll and tap on cell. Please help me with that.Thanks